# configuring server to receive traffic at a specific ip address

Tags: 14.04

I have a Go program (full program at this gist https://gist.github.com/42a45b3926e733ef7b34) that when I run on my local machine starts a server and handles two routes localhost:8080 and localhost:8080/login. It does this by listening and serving on port 8080

> err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)

I installed Go on an ubuntu server and am able to run the program, however, when I go to my ip addresss 107.170.XX.XX:8080 and/or 107.170.XX.XX:8080/login, my browser appears to be trying to connect and then I get a message that a page isn't available

I assumed that my ip address on the remote server was, for the purpose of running this program, similar to localhost on my local machine, in that if I simply run the Go program on my localmachine and can view it in the browser, shouldn't I be able to do the same on the remote machine by going to the IP address?

Is there some other type of configuration I need to set up in order to connect to the program at my ip address?

Note, when I configured the ip tables, it was done to receive connections on port 22 for SSH and 80 for web traffic.

Comment: You also need to open up 8080 in iptables. Plus does `http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)` make the application listen on all interfaces or just loopback? You can check this by running your application and running `netstat -tlnp`

Comment: @shutupsquare thanks, I ran `netstat -tlnp` and it says it requires an argument.

Comment: Then your probably running an operating other than Ubuntu, or you have installed some other netstat, or you entered it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble with modern browsers is, they hide the underlying error message in the sake of user friendlyness.

Try using telnet to access your program

> telnet 107.170.xxx.xx 8080

If it times out, you're probably firewalled. If it returns immediately, then either your program is not correctly bound on the ubuntu server or a firewall rejects your request.

Note: You wrote you have allowed firewall port 80, yet write your program sits at 8080. Thus you would be firewalling your program away from everyone.

Check netstat on the server to see where your program is bound to:

> netstat -tulpen

This lists all programs with open listening sockets along their processid/names (if you are root or owner of them). If your program is bound to one of the external addresses or the ephemeral port "::" it can only be the firewall.

If your program is listening on 127.0.0.1 it will only be reachable on the same system.